# PHP Get String within [[ ]] brackets to array

Tags: php, regex, string

I am writing some snippet script with PHP,

I have these kind of string variable

```
 $msg="Dear [[5]]
    We wish to continue the lesson with the [[6]]";
```

i need to grab 5 and 6 from this $msg and assign to an array
ex array(5,6)

because those are the snippets numbers, any one know how to do that using PHP

thank you for help

Comment: Foreseeing your next step, it might be easier to use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://us.php.net/preg_replace_callback) to find and substitute these markers in one step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php):

```
$msg = "Dear [[5]] We wish to continue the lesson with the [[6]]";
preg_match_all("/\[\[(\d+)\]\]/", $msg, $matches);
```

If there is a match, `$matches[1]` will then contain an array with the matched numbers:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 5
    [1] => 6
)
```

**[DEMO](http://ideone.com/52Xxh)**.

Comment: I applied this to my script 
my string was "test closingdear [[12]]" and it gaves me this kind of array in var dump 
array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(6) "[[12]]" } [1]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "12" } } 
there is extra items, any idea what is going here :)

Comment: @SunethKalhara: Can you give me the exact line you executed? You need to consider only the first position of the resulting array.

Comment: $rulz="test closingdear [[12]]";
preg_match_all("/\[\[(\d+)\]\]/", $rulz, $matches);                      
var_dump($matches);

Comment: @SunethKalhara: You didn't escape the `[` and `]` like in my example. They are special regex characters. Also, you need to consider only `$matches[1]`. Check this demo http://ideone.com/IbHhI.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you want:

```
<?php

$msg = "Dear [[5]]
 We wish to continue the lesson with the [[6]]";

preg_match_all('/\[\[([0-9+])\]\]/', $msg, $array);

$array = $array[1];

print_r($array);

?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 5
    [1] => 6
)
```

Comment: I don't really see how's this any different from my answer.

Comment: I was typing this when there was no answer :)

Comment: $array = $array[0]; is worked for me, do you know why is that :)

Comment: Because preg_match places all found in index[0] which isn't what you want and from that each () of pattern will be stored in other indexes starting from 1. In this case in our pattern, we have only 1 parentheses so the index[1] would be where the found data will be stored ...